# Highlighting issue in qml ListView

Tags: qml

I have a qml file i.e. `test.qml` which i'm calling from the main qml file. `test.qml` shows file and folder in the `ListView`.
I'm able to successfully select items within in a `ListView` but the selected item is not highlighted on click.

Here is my working code of test.qml in which i'm trying to `highlight` the selected item to be "blue"

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 400
    height: 400
    color: "white"

    property string filelist: '{"files":[{"name":"file1.txt","size":1024,"type":"file"},{"name":"file2.jpg","size":2048,"type":"file"},{"name":"directory1","type":"directory"},{"name":"file3.docx","size":5120,"type":"file"},{"name":"directory2","type":"directory"}]}'

    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: JSON.parse(filelist).files // Parse the JSON string into a model

        delegate: Item {
            width: ListView.view.width
            height: 50

            Rectangle {
                width:parent.width
                height: parent.height
                anchors.fill: parent
                color: ListView.isCurrentItem ? "blue" : "transparent"

                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                 //   acceptedButtons: Qt.RightButton
                    onClicked: (mouse)=>{
                               console.log(modelData.name)
                    }
                }

                Image {
                    id: iconImage
                    width: 24
                    height: 24
                    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                    source: modelData.type === 'file' ? "file-icon.png" : "directory-icon.png"
                }

                Text {
                    text: modelData.name
                    anchors.verticalCenter: iconImage.verticalCenter
                    anchors.left: iconImage.right
                    anchors.leftMargin: 10
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two mistakes in your code. First of all, you don't change **ListView** **currentIndex** value **(1)**. The second thing you need to call **ListView.isCurrentItem** directly on your delegate like this **item.ListView.isCurrentItem** where **item** is your main delegate id **(2)**. Below fixed code:

```
ListView {
        id: listView
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: JSON.parse(filelist).files // Parse the JSON string into a model
        onCurrentIndexChanged:{
            console.log(currentIndex)
        }
        delegate: Item {
            id: item
            width: ListView.view.width
            height: 50

            Rectangle {
                width:parent.width
                height: parent.height
                anchors.fill: parent
                color: item.ListView.isCurrentItem ? "blue" : "transparent"  // (2)

                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    onClicked: (mouse)=>{
                                    console.log(modelData.name)
                                    listView.currentIndex = index  // Set currentIndex value (1)
                    }
                }

                Image {
                    id: iconImage
                    width: 24
                    height: 24
                    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                    source: modelData.type === 'file' ? "file-icon.png" : "directory-icon.png"
                }

                Text {
                    text: modelData.name
                    anchors.verticalCenter: iconImage.verticalCenter
                    anchors.left: iconImage.right
                    anchors.leftMargin: 10
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could also specify [`highlight`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-listview.html#highlight-prop) in order to indicate the current item.

Comment: Yes, you're right. There are also some other options.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, when working with ListView attached properties, I found that it's best to alias them at the start of your delegate. This is because the attached properties are sometimes only available at the top-level of your delegate and may not be equivalent available within, so, we resolve the attached properties as soon as property.

```
delegate: Item {
    property ListView listView: ListView.view
    property bool isCurrentItem: ListView.isCurrentItem
```

You may like to consider is setting `highlightRangeMode`. This has the additional benefit of a 'no-code' automatic setting of currentIndex for some instances of scrolling. However, the flexibility/use-case of this setting is somewhat limited.

```
ListView {
    highlightRangeMode: ListView.StrictlyEnforceRange
```

I noticed that you use MouseArea with Image with Text. Are you aware of the component ItemDelegate that has all these features? e.g.

```
ItemDelegate {
    icon.width: 24
    icon.height: 24
    icon.source: modelData.type === 'file' ? "file-icon.png" : "directory-icon.png"
    text: modelData.name
    onClicked: listView.currentIndex = index
}
```

Here's a demonstration of the above concepts:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    property string filelist: '{"files":[{"name":"file1.txt","size":1024,"type":"file"},{"name":"file2.jpg","size":2048,"type":"file"},{"name":"directory1","type":"directory"},{"name":"file3.docx","size":5120,"type":"file"},{"name":"directory2","type":"directory"}]}'
    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: JSON.parse(filelist).files // Parse the JSON string into a model
        highlightRangeMode: ListView.StrictlyEnforceRange
        preferredHighlightBegin: height/2
        preferredHighlightEnd: height/2
        delegate: ItemDelegate {
            property ListView listView: ListView.view
            property bool isCurrent: ListView.isCurrent
            width: listView.width
            icon.width: 24
            icon.height: 24
            icon.source: modelData.type
            text: modelData.name
            onClicked: listView.currentIndex = index
        }
        highlight: Rectangle { color: "lightblue" }
    }
}
// directory.svg : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Esri/calcite-ui-icons/master/icons/folder-32.svg
// file.svg : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Esri/calcite-ui-icons/master/icons/file-32.svg
```

You can [Try it online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)